# I get "React not defined" when using express, create-react-app and babel-node

Tags: reactjs, express, create-react-app, babel-node, babel-register

I just wanted to enable server-side rendering with react and create-react-app.

I've written a server/index.js file which should return a simple react component as a string.

```
//require('import-export');
//require('babel-register')({ ignore: /\/(build|node_modules)\//, presets: ['react-app', 'es2015', 'react'] });
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const index = require('./index.js');
const react = require('react');
const reactServerDom = require('react-dom/server');
const renderToString = reactServerDom.renderToString;
const ourComponent = require('../src/App.js');
const app = express();

// Setup logger
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] :response-time ms'));

// Serve static assets - NEEDS TO BE ACTIVATED LATER WHEN RENDERTOSTRING WORKS!
//app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html');
  let result = '';
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    const ReactApp = renderToString(react.createElement(ourComponent));
    result = data.replace('{{SSR}}', ReactApp);
    res.send(result);
  });
});

const port = 9007;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${ port }`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

The component that should be rendered is just the sample component which everyone gets from create-react-app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Inside my package.json I have following command to start the server with babel-node using the command **yarn server** or **npm run server**:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "server": "NODE_ENV=development babel-node --presets=es2015,react server/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
...
```

But I still get following error:

```
$ NODE_ENV=development babel-node --presets=es2015,react server/index.js
/home/sonnenfeld/ssr-render/src/logo.svg:4
React.createElement(
^

ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

And if I remove the svg from the component I get another error:

```
SyntaxError: /home/sonnenfeld/ssr-render/src/App.css: Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | .App {
    | ^
  2 |   text-align: center;
  3 | }
  4 |
```

I have already tried the babel hook with babel-register, but also no success.

What would be a good approach to transpile my server.js and all dependencies to vanilla javascript, when using create-react-app with express?

Comment: I think the problem is with your component.

Comment: i think, you need to import `React` in `ourComponent` also, with the name of `React` not `react`. or you can try one thing, import react like this `const React = require('react');` then is use `React` at all the places instead of `react` it should work.

Comment: the component is just the sample component from create-react-app. I will edit my post and insert the component there.

Comment: @MayankShukla I already have `import React` in my component. And the component can also have subcomponents. And all of them should transpile with babel automatically to vanilla javascript. Thats the sense of using babel-node. But he is just not transpiling and I dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Side Rendering can be really hard. So I switched entirely to next-js.

The problem with styled components was solved with an official workaround https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#server-side-rendering

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. For my case, it seems that express server detects the svg files as a React component, therefore it searches for React import inside the svg file. I'm not using webpack on my project, because I do not want to make it even more complicated than it is, but cannot find any solutions to it without NextJS as you've suggested. Any ideas?